# Can I persist an object in catch field?

Tags: java, jpa, exception, jakarta-ee, try-catch

In my case, the Article and Tag is a unidirectional ManyToMany relationship.

**Article.class**

```
@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany 
    @JoinTable(name = "ARTICLE_TAG", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    ...

}
```

**Tag.class**

```
@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable {


    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String tagValue;

    // tagType can be category or keyword
    private TagType tagType;

}
```

So as you can see, I need to set the Tag in my article. Some Tags may already be saved to the database before, so my service method will first check it, if the tag already existed, set it. If not, the method will cause a NoResultException, then I catch the Exception and want to do the save operation in the catch field as well as set the tag. Here is the code

**ArticleSerivce.class**

```
public void createArticle(ArticleDTO articleDTO) throws Exception {
    Article article = new Article();

    // check and then set tags;
    Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
    tags.addAll(validateKeywords(articleDTO.getKeywords()));
    article.setTags(tags);

    ...

    articleService.createArticle(article);
}

private Set<Tag> validateKeywords(String[] keywords) {
    Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
    if (keywords.length != 0) {
        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            try {
                // first check that if the tag is already existed
                Tag tag = tagService.findTagByValue(keyword);
                tags.add(tag);
            } catch (NoResultException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                // if doesn't existed, then create it
                Tag tag = new Tag(TagType.KEYWORD);
                tag.setTagValue(keyword);
                tagService.createTag(tag);
                tags.add(tag);
            }
        }
    }

    return tags;
}
```

And the question is, I do found that the **NoResultException** has been caught because the info has been printed in the output console, I also debugged the application and found that the tag has been created but with wired id **(imagine that I have 4 tags already in my dataTable and their id are 1,2,3,4, then I create 3 tags that not exist, but the id comes 5, 6, *null*, why the last one's id not *7*?)**. Finally, the article can't be created, there's no error or any info in my output console, and of course, no record in my ARTICLE dataTable. It's so wired! What's wrong there? I guess maybe something happened in the catch field. So please help me, thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like  the transaction was rolled back after the exception  has been thrown.

Comment: JPA spec states: "Runtime exceptions other than the NoResultException, NonUniqueResultException,
QueryTimeoutException, and LockTimeoutException thrown by the methods of the
Query, TypedQuery, and StoredProcedureQuery interfaces other than those methods specified
below cause the current transaction to be marked for rollback if the persistence context is joined to
the transaction."  So it isn't rolling back the transaction.  No clue what you are doing though or how it relates to the Article

Comment: What does 'tag has been created but with wired id' mean?  Your code should persist a Tag and the DB would assign the ID when it gets inserted. What is your application printing off?  Are you passing back the tag that has its ID set?

Comment: @Chris I have edited my question, maybe it will be the clue, the id is not as I predicted that should be 5, 6, 7, but comes to 5, 6, null, so I'm confused about it.

Comment: You still haven't shown anything, like the createArticle method, the SQL being used etc that would help figure out what is going wrong or where it might be going wrong.